# Check if a number is in ranges values ​contained in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array with couple of values like :

```js
let myvar = 17
let myarray = [
    { start: 1, end: 10 },
    { start: 15, end: 22 },
    { start: 44, end: 47 }
]
```

I am looking for how to check if a variable is between the start and end of one of the objects in the array.

if myvar = 17, myfunction return true, because 17 is between 15 and 22 (the second object { start 15, end: 22 }), but if myvar = 12, myfunction return false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [**some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let data =
[
    { start: 1, end: 10 },
    { start: 15, end: 22 },
    { start: 44, end: 47 }
]

let num = 17

let result = data.some(d => d.start <=num && d.end >= num  )
console.log(result)
```

---

Update:
If you want to do it via function,then you can do it as below:

```js
let myArray =
[
    { start: 1, end: 10 },
    { start: 15, end: 22 },
    { start: 44, end: 47 }
]

let myVar = 12

const myFunc = (num,data) => data.some(d => d.start <=num && d.end >= num)

console.log(myFunc(myVar,myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

lucumt answer is not wrong but it didn't tell me which child of data is true. it just told me that it exists in there. so for that reason, I would use for each.

```js
let data =
[
    { start: 1, end: 10 },
    { start: 15, end: 22 },
    { start: 44, end: 47 }
]

let num = 17


data.forEach(dc => {
    // dc = data child
        if (dc.start <= num && dc.end >= num) {

            console.log(dc);
            console.log(dc.start);
            console.log(dc.end);
        }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but in my case, i just want boolean response, i dont care about précision of object.